# VB.NET LINQ query Where with AndAlso and Or

Tags: vb.net, linq

In VB.NET, if I am doing a [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query that looks like this:

```
From a in entitity.name
Where a.id = id _
AndAlso a.date < currentDate _
AndAlso a.statusId = 1 Or a.statusId = 3
Select
```

On line 4, will the `or` clause evaluate to return all entities with a statusId of 3, or will it only return the entities that fit the other criteria and have a statusId of 1 or 3?

If that line were changed to

```
 AndAlso (a.statusId = 1 Or a.statusId = 3)
```

How would that change the expected results?

Comment: Have you tried this to see? Note that I wouldn't expect this to be LINQ-specific at all... it's just a matter of [VB precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx).

Comment: Don't use `Or` but `OrElse` (and `AndAlso` instead of `And`). `Or` evaluates both sides. So `OrElse` is a short-circuiting operator, `Or` is not. With `OrElse` if the first is `True` then the whole condition is true - it doesn't need to evaluate the second.

Comment: I have not tried it.  I currently have the parentheses around the Or clause, I am probably a day away from scripting out my DB, implementing my repository methods in my business logic, and creating a view model/ controller.  I searched for a case of AndAlso being used with Or in a VB linq query and came up empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.NET, conjunction (And, AndAlso) operators occur before inclusive disjunction (Or, OrElse) operators. See *[Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx)*.

So as soon as a.statusId = 3 is true, it will return true.

And adding parenthesis

```
AndAlso (a.statusId = 1 Or a.statusId = 3)
```

will therefore change the behaviour

from:

```
return TRUE if (a.id = id AND a.date < currentDate AND a.statusId = 1) OR a.statusId = 3
```

to:

```
return TRUE if a.id = id AND a.date < currentDate AND (a.statusId = 1 OR a.statusId = 3)
```

Comment: Correct, but doesn't explain HOW it would change the results, as asked above.

Answer (score 1):

```
From a in entitity.name
Where a.id = id _
AndAlso a.date < currentDate _
AndAlso a.statusId = 1 Or a.statusId = 3
Select
```

is equivalent to having (notice the addition of parentheses below):

```
From a in entitity.name
Where (a.id = id _
AndAlso a.date < currentDate _
AndAlso a.statusId = 1) Or (a.statusId = 3)
Select
```

Which would return any results where the id matches, the date is less than currentDate, and the status is 1. It will also return ANY results where the statusId is 3.

Whereas having:

```
From a in entitity.name
Where a.id = id _
AndAlso a.date < currentDate _
AndAlso (a.statusId = 1 Or a.statusId = 3)
Select
```

Would then return any results where the id matches, the date is less than currentDate, and the status is 1 or 3.

This is the same type of behavior you would see in SQL, or even in general math. `1 + 2 * 3` does not yield the same result as `(1 + 2) * 3`. It changes the order of operations/the meaning of the statement completely (at least in this case).